# Angular, moving back and quickly moving forward causes problems (component is not destroyed)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ngrx

I will try to simplify the application for the purpose of this question. Let's say we have two pages:

1. /home
2. /edit

When going on the `/edit` page, a request `beginEdit` is done to the back end. When navigating away from the `/edit` page (i.e to `/home`), an `endEdit` request is done to the back end. I have a `canDeactivate` guard which catches the navigation and prompts the user if he/she wants to set a parameter to true or false (the parameter doesn't matter in this example). The problem is that when I simulate a slow network speed and navigate to `/home` (or just press back) and then quickly press browser forward, the request has gone through but the component has not been destroyed. So anything I do on the page is not valid anymore. I can't move the request to `ngOnDestroy()` because I must be sure that the request has gone through.

Is there a good way to tackle this problem?

**EDIT:** I've added a [sample](https://candeactivate-ffe53b.stackblitz.io/component-one).

1. Go to component one [(link)](https://candeactivate-ffe53b.stackblitz.io/component-one)
2. Click the `Component Two` button
3. Click the `Component One` button
4. I've added some delays... spam the browser's forward button until it becomes active
5. Check console along the way

Once the `endEdit` API has been called on the `Component Two` page, it should always destroy the component.

Comment: Maybe using a resolver?? [Check it out](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)

Comment: It's always tempting to think that the problem is in the framework, but the probability of the bug being in your code is much higher. Post your code. Ideally, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I've edited my post and added a minimal example. I'm not blaming the framework but while writing out that example I already saw some new things. For example, I noticed that the navigation happens despite having the promise unresolved but the component still isn't destroyed. Still no idea how to solve this though.